# what is the difference between waiting time and respond time in cpu scheduling

Tags: operating-system

I've been looking online for a while, trying to find the difference on these two terms but I cannot seem to get a clear answer and I am simply getting confused. If waiting time is  amount of time a process has been waiting in the ready queue waiting for cpu (CPU respond?) so what the difference with respond time?

Could someone explain the difference to me. A nice and descriptive article would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be very precise:

**Waiting Time**:- The time processes spend in the Ready Queue Waiting their turn to get on the CPU.

1. Here, you have to understand that CPU is not Responding, but it is indexing the processes in the Ready queue.
2. In this particular time, the Processes are not issuing any command and that's why CPU is not responding anything.

---

**Response Time**:-

1. It is the time taken in an interactive program.
2. Time counted from the issuance of a command by the processes to the commence of a response by the CPU to that command.

With these points, i hope you will understand the basic concept behind these terms. Reply if you are still unsure about these terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so when a process got CPU, the process will start to issuance of a command to CPU and then waiting respond from CPU?

Comment: My confusion is, will the Response time be a subset of Waiting time?
I mean, in a scenario where,
1. The process is created and is in the ready queue.
2. Then after 5 secs it is picked for execution, it runs non-stop for 10 secs and then the process is terminated.

In this scenario, RT is 5 sec for sure. BT is 10 secs.
**But then, WT will be 0 sec or 5 sec?**

Answer (score 8):

Response Time:
Duration between job submission and getting the first time to be executed by CPU.

Waiting Time:
Amount of time the job is present in the ready queue.

Answer (score 4):

When the process gets the CPU execution for the first time this is called response time and this is also called waiting time.
But waiting time again can be increased because we are not sure that a process will be executed properly only at one time.
It can be wait again in the ready queue for any kind of interruption or for I/O and then again will get the excess of CPU.
Thus waiting time can be increased but response times remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Response time:**
Time between:

1. Process is ready.(Arrival Time)
2. Process is completed.(Completion Time)

can be calculated:

- C: Computation time
- R: Response time
- T: Period
- R(i)0= C(i)
- R(i)1= C(i) + sum of([R(i)/T(j)]* C(j))
- where i is self and j are tasks with higher priority than i.

**Waiting time**
Time between:

1. Process is ready.(Arrival Time)
2. Process is started (Running)

Reference:
Real-Time Systems Design and Analysis @Laplante

Answer (score 0):

Waiting Time: Time taken up by the process while waiting for any I/O Operation (for e.g. - waiting for a printer/scanner or key press etc)

By seeing the formula, we can see that Waiting time can also be defined as whole time taken up by process from arrival in the ready queue to completion - duration of execution of the process by the CPU.

Formula:   Turn Around Time - Burst Time.

AND

Response Time: can be defined as time at which the process gets the CPU for the *FIRST TIME* - Time of arrival of the process in main memory(that is ready queue).

You can use Gantt Chart to determine the time at which the process gets the CPU for the *FIRST TIME*

Formula: Time at which CPU get the process for the First time - its Arrival Time.